# How to use and operator in where clause with sequelize in nodejs

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I want to search some rows from the database.

```
Phones.findAndCountAll({
        where: {
            id: (req.body.id) ?  req.body.id : { $ne: null },
            description: (req.body.description) ? { $like: '%' + req.body.description.trim() + '%' } : { $ne: null },
            price: {
                $and: {
                  {(req.body.st_price) ? {$gte: req.body.st_price}  : { $ne: null } },
                  {(req.body.en_price) ? {$lte: req.body.en_price}  : { $ne: null } },
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

But when I run this it doesnt work. I want to search if request.body.? exist. Should I use the between operator?
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think , you should build your query first and then use it inside `sequelize` :

```
let price_conditions = {};
if(req.body.st_price){
    price_conditions['$gte'] = req.body.st_price;
}
if(req.body.en_price){
    price_conditions['$lte'] = req.body.st_price;
}
price_conditions['$ne'] = null;

Phones.findAndCountAll({
    where: {
        id: (req.body.id) ?  req.body.id : { $ne: null },
        description: (req.body.description) ? { $like: '%' + req.body.description.trim() + '%' } : { $ne: null },
        price : price_conditions
    }
})
```

For More Detail : **[DO READ](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#combinations)**